# declaring a list with a generic stored in a variable

Tags: c#, generics, quartz.net

I want to go through a switch statement to determine what type to make something that contains a generic with.

Below is a silly, but illustrative bit of code that shows what I am trying to do:

```
Type tempType;
switch(number)
{
   case 0:
      tempType = typeof(int);
      break;
   case 1:
      tempType = typeof(bool);
      break;
   case 2:
      tempType = typeof(long);
      break;
}

List<tempType> theList = new List<tempType>();
```

When I try this it gives the error:

> The type or namespace name 'tempType' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

My assumption on why is because it is looking for types that are globally available there, and is not looking in the local member variables of this method.  How can I do something like this?

EDIT:
To give a bit more context, I am trying to use Quartz.NET, and I am trying to create different jobs with it, so each of the types in this example are different Job Classes, each with their specific execute commands.  the different cases are when I want to access that specific job class.  Then I would create the job via:

```
tempJob = JobBuilder.Create<tempType>()
            .WithIdentity("SomeJob " + i)
            .UsingJobData()
            .Build();
```

Comment: Can you describe why you need to do this; place this requirement in context, because it's likely not going to be the best way of solving that problem.

Comment: I added the context you requested.

Comment: As the `Create` method shows there, you should probably just be specifying the class in the generic argument to the method.  If you don't do that then the next method in the fluent interface won't know (at compile time) what the type is, so they won't be able to do anything with the `List`.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @Servy I was trying to do some optimization by not repeating the .withIdentity().usingjobdata().build(), since all of the jobs will need that, but each class in the generic had to be different.  I just hate having to repeat the same thing multiple times since it makes maintainability worse.  But on the plus side, I know more about how generics work under the hood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use generics the compiler has to know the type at compile-time; you can not determine the type at runtime and create a generic.  If you don't know the type until runtime, you would generally just use a List.

You could use reflection to create a particular type instantiation at runtime, but instantiating to a particular type is primarily useful to the compiler for type inference; if the compiler doesn't know, there's not a lot of reason for your program to care at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

You may try to do next:

```
        Type tempType = typeof(int);
        switch (number)
        {
            case 0:
                tempType = typeof(int);
                break;
            case 1:
                tempType = typeof(bool);
                break;
            case 2:
                tempType = typeof(long);
                break;
        }

        Type customListType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(tempType);
        IList objectList = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(customListType);
```

but IList is not generic interface so you will have `object`s there.

Answer (score 0):

You can user reflection to create an instance of `List` with a `Type` not known until runtime, but because it needs to be created in this manor you can't use it as a strongly typed list (again, since the type isn't know at compile time) you'll be forced to treat it as a non-generic `IList`, `dynamic`, or `object`.

Answer (score 0):

Your tempType will be resolved when you run the program but you are trying to create a List<> of that unknown type before runtime. You can't do that.

You need to resolve that tempType at runtime and create your List at runtime too. Use Reflection facilities to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to do something like

```
Type tempType ;
var number = 0;
switch(number)
{
    case 0:
        tempType = typeof(Quartz.Job.DirectoryScanJob);
        break;

    ... 

    default :
        tempType = typeof(Quartz.Job.NoOpJob);
        break;
}


int i = 0;
var tempJob = JobBuilder.Create()
        .OfType(tempType)
        .WithIdentity("SomeJob " + i)             
        .Build();
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll notice that this doesn't work either:

```
Type tempType = typeof(int);
List<tempType> theList = new List<tempType>();
```

Basically, the type of the generic needs to be known at compile-time; you can't create it at run-time. There are all sorts of reasons for this, as the compiler wouldn't be able to enforce the various rules around generics if it didn't know what type it was.

Just use a non-generic `List`.